# How can i avoid android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException error

Tags: android

I am beginner who training mobile using android.
I found out an error then i can't solve the problem.
I tried to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException during android training,
this is error in Android Mornitor

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
                                                                             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
                                                                             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
                                                                             at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
                                                                             at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
                                                                             at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:605)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$Android.connectSocket(Platform.java:190)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:267)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
                                                                             at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
                                                                             at com.jfdimarzio.httpreqest.MainActivity$HttpTest.doPostRequest(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                             at com.jfdimarzio.httpreqest.MainActivity.login(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                             at com.jfdimarzio.httpreqest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is my code...

//AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.jfdimarzio.httpreqest">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

////MainActivity.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.httpreqest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.VectorEnabledTintResources;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button login_btn ;
    private EditText username_view;
    private EditText email_view;
    private EditText password_view;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    private String username, password, email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        email_view = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        login_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        login_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void login () {
        username = username_view.getText().toString();
        email = email_view.getText().toString();
        password = password_view.getText().toString();

        HttpTest httpTest = new HttpTest();
        String jsonData = httpTest.bowlingJson(username, email, password);
        try {
            String response = httpTest.doPostRequest("http://172.16.32.61/login/login.php", jsonData);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Respond: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private class HttpTest {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        public final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        String doPostRequest(String url) throws IOException {
            Request reqest = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(reqest).execute();
            return  response.body().toString();
        }

        String doPostRequest(String url, String json) throws IOException {
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            Response response = call.execute();
            return response.body().string();
        }

        String bowlingJson(String username, String email, String password) {
            String json = "{'username':'" + username + "',"
                    + "'email':'" + email + "',"
                    + "'password':'" + password + "'}";

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), json, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask:

Comment: Be aware asynctask is very good to start learning but it has [pitfalls](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/)

Comment: Thank you for information :)

Comment: thank very much. successful!